# Android Firestore check if a field exists

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I need help solving a problem.
I'm new to Firestore, I come from MySQL.
I have a registration form where the user registers (Restaurateur), the app works, the data is saved perfectly.
The problem however is that when the user registers, I can not block the registration if the restaurant's name is the same as another restaurant already present in the Database.

In the code first check if there is an identical document, if it does not exist, I want to check the name of the restaurant, and if it is the same as another name block everything and stop the recording.

I tried to do this by inserting `dbristoratore.collection (" Restaurateurs "). WhereEqualTo (" name_RistoranteR ", nameRistoranteR);` in the condition of the IF but nothing.
But if I recall it in a method it works, but after the problem it is that I do not know how to switch to registration in case the name of the restaurant was free.
The code is this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_r_r_start);

        nomeristoratore =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        cognomeristoratore =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        nomeristorante = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        data_nascitaristoratore =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        id_fkristoratore =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        numero_telefonoristoratore =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);

        rGroupristoratore = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup2);

        registraristoratore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        registraristoratore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registrazioneRistoratore();
            }

            private void registrazioneRistoratore() {
                final String nomeR = nomeristoratore.getText().toString();
                final String cognomeR = cognomeristoratore.getText().toString();
                final String nomeRistoranteR = nomeristorante.getText().toString();
                final String dataR = data_nascitaristoratore.getText().toString();
                final String id_fk_R = id_fkristoratore.getText().toString();
                final String numero_telefono_R = numero_telefonoristoratore.getText().toString();
                final String sessoR = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rGroupristoratore.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();








                if (nomeR.isEmpty()){
                    nomeristoratore.setError("Inserisci il tuo nome");
                    nomeristoratore.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (cognomeR.isEmpty()){
                    cognomeristoratore.setError("Inserisci il tuo cognome");
                    cognomeristoratore.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (dataR.isEmpty()){
                    data_nascitaristoratore.setError("Inserisci la tua data di nascita");
                    data_nascitaristoratore.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (dataR.length() != 10){
                    data_nascitaristoratore.setError("Formato data errato");
                    data_nascitaristoratore.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (nomeRistoranteR.isEmpty()){
                    nomeristorante.setError("Inserisci il nome del ristorante");
                    nomeristorante.requestFocus();
                    return;

                }

                dbristoratore.collection("Ristoratori").document(id_fk_R).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sei già registrato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            // cognome.setError("Team with same name already exists");
                            //cognome.requestFocus();


                        } else if(("nome_ristoranteR".equals(nomeRistoranteR))
                        ) {
                            dbristoratore.collection("Ristoratori").whereEqualTo("nome_ristoranteR", nomeRistoranteR);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Use another Name restaurant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        }

                            else {

                        //If team with same name doesn't exist, save it
                        dbristoratore.collection("Ristoratori").document(id_fk_R).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();


                                //Check if user is already in a team
                                //TeamMap data1 = new TeamMap(teamNameText, teamCountryText, Username);
                                RistoratoreMap data2 = new RistoratoreMap(nomeR, cognomeR, dataR, nomeRistoranteR, numero_telefono_R, id_fk_R, sessoR);
                                dbristoratore.collection("Ristoratori").document(id_fk_R).set(data2).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                    // Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                                    // data.put("username", Username);
                                    //  db.collection("TeamUsers").document(teamNameText).set(data);
                                    //  Map<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<>();
                                    //  data2.put("User's team", teamNameText);

                                    //  db.collection("Users").document(teamNameText).set(data2).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(R_r_start.this, onboarding_r.class));

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrato con successo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore, prova a disinstallare l'app e installarla di nuovo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }



                }


                    });}});}}
```

I hope I have explained myself well, if you have any ideas on how to help me please.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: I have 2 collections, one "Restaurateurs" and the other "Customers". In the Ristoratori collection I have the documents that save with the name id_fk_r and in the collection Customers I have the documents that save with the name id_fk_c.

Comment: Instead of explaining how your database looks like please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Alex Mamo i have add a image of database

Comment: What is the result when you hardcode a restaurant name `dbristoratore.collection("Ristaratori").whereEqualTo (" name_RistoranteR ", "Big Pizza");`? Does it return one item?

Comment: It does not return anything, but if I add a Toast to the condition it makes it appear to me.

Comment: So it's working, then what is the problem?

Comment: is that I do not know how to put it in the if loop condition to check if it exists in the Database

Comment: else if(("nome_ristoranteR".equals(nomeRistoranteR))
                        ) {
                            dbristoratore.collection("Ristoratori").whereEqualTo("nome_ristoranteR", nomeRistoranteR);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Use another Name restaurant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        }

Comment: This IF condition don't work, it does not return anything.